# InfluxDB design storing energy values from SMA EM meter

Tags: logging, schema, influxdb, energy

I am trying to figure out the best way to store lots of values in influxdb.

The SMA energy meter can measure SUMS and phase L1 to L3

Both Import "+" and Export "-"

And the current average "power" and Energy meter reading kwh counter "energy"

So here are the values for SUMS

- Active power/energy +
- Active power/energy −
- Reactive power/energy +
- Reactive power/energy −
- Apparent power/energy +
- Apparent power/energy −
- Power factor

For the individual phases 
you have the above metrics plus

- Electric current
- voltage

I am thinking something like this in linecode

```
Active_power+, phase=[1,2,3,SUM], value=###
energy+, phase=[1,2,3,SUM], value=###
```

So each metric is one serie with the phase as tag. 
Since I am new to the influxdb I wonder if this is that the best way to store the values or if I can do it in any more efficient way. 
For example is it better to have each Phase+ Sums as serie

```
L1,direction=[import,export],P="currentpower_value",V=volt_value,I="eletric_current_value",PF="power factor value", Q=reactivepower, S=Apparent_power
```

More information about the SMA energy meter is available here:
http://www.sma.de/fileadmin/content/global/Partner/Documents/SMA_Labs/EMETER-Protokoll-TI-en-10.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I would consider a slightly different schema (provided that my understanding is correct).

Assuming that you have more than one meter that you're monitoring,

Measurement: `sma_energy_meter`

Tags: `meter_id` `phase`.

Fields: `active_power+` `active_power-` `reactive_power+` `reactive_power-` `apparent_power+` `apparent_power-` `power_factor` `current` `voltage`

So an example point in line protocol would look like

```
sma_energy_meter,meter_id=xxx,phase=[1,2,3,SUM] active_power+=2,active_power-=4,reactive_power+=2,reactive_power-=4,apparent_power+=2,apparent_power-=4,power_factor=2,current=2,voltage=23
```

Comment: Thanks that Is probably the most clear way to do it.
There is also the fields for the counters. Maybe they should be on another serie? 

    Active_counter+  
    Active_counter-
    reactive_counter+
    reactive_counter-
   apparent_counter+

Comment: Not sure I follow completely. Why not just have them in the same series?